# How to skip the code execution from PhantomJS or grover

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, grover

The problem is next: I have JavaScript code in my application and I want to skip/hide some peace of code from PhantomJS and grover checking/execution.

So, **how can I skip/hide the code execution from PhantomJS or grover?**

Note: the problem has occurred when I was writing the JavaScript unit-tests.
But I think it would be helpful in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap the code with simple verification:

```
if (!window['phantom'] && !window['_phantom']) {
  // your code here...
}
```

In this case the code in your application will be executed as normal but skipped when the PhantomJS or grover will inspect it.

*Notes*:

- I use "window['phantom']" - because my application is minimized using google closure
  compiler, in other case you can easily use (!window.phantom &&
  !window._phantom);
- window['_phantom'] - indicates presence PhantomJS using **grover** tool.